# ipfs daemon error?

Tags: ipfs

```
bc@bc-HP-Pro-3090-Microtower-PC:~/supply-chain$ ipfs daemon --writable=true
Initializing daemon...
Adjusting current ulimit to 2048...
Successfully raised file descriptor limit to 2048.
Swarm listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/4001
Swarm listening on /ip4/172.17.0.1/tcp/4001
Swarm listening on /ip4/172.18.0.1/tcp/4001
Swarm listening on /ip4/172.20.0.1/tcp/4001
Swarm listening on /ip4/172.21.0.1/tcp/4001
Swarm listening on /ip4/192.168.1.78/tcp/4001
Swarm listening on /ip6/::1/tcp/4001
API server listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/5001
Error: serveHTTPGateway: manet.Listen(/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/8080) failed: listen tcp4 127.0.0.1:8080: bind: address already in use
```

Answer (score 4):

IPFS daemon exposes by default three services on three different ports:

- **4001** peer2p which allows to join the network
- **5001** API server serving the full API (see [documentation](https://docs.ipfs.io/reference/api/http/))
- **8080** Gateway server exposing a read only (like  http://localhost:8080/ipfs/QmaG4FuMqEBnQNn3C8XJ5bpW8kLs7zq2ZXgHptJHbKDDVx)

The exception  `Error: serveHTTPGateway: manet.Listen(/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/8080) failed: listen tcp4 127.0.0.1:8080: bind: address already in use` means that IPFS daemon can't start the gateway because you already have something running on this port.

To find what program runs on the port 8080 an stop it, you can execute the following command:

```
$ netstat -a | grep 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cant stop the program running on port 8080 or you dont want to stop, then go in your home directory, then in .ipfs folder and change the port number in config file.